# Interleaving lists based on input from a function

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that interleaves a list of lists. The number of sublists in the main list is defined by user input. I was able to get the interleaved result to work, but it isn't correct simply because I hardcoded variables to store two lists containing interleaved items. I am a beginner using Python and don't have much experience in programming in general.

The code below includes a list constant that contains a list of tuples named `inlist`. The items in `inlist` will only be added to a sublist (`mylist_a` or `mylist_b`) if they are available, which is indicated by a `1` or `0` in each tuple.

I evaluate each tuple and add only those items that have a 1 in "inlist".

my code:

```
inlist = [('apples', 1), ('oranges', 0), ('bananas', 0), ('grapes', 1),
          ('strawberries', 1), ('pears', 1), ('cucumbers', 0), ('lettuce', 0),
          ('tomatos', 0), ('onions', 0), ('garlic', 1), ('pineapples', 1)]

mainlist = []
mylist_a = []
mylist_b = []
counter = 1
for i in inlist:
    if i[1] == 1:
        counter += 1
        if i[1] == 1 and counter % 2 == 0:
            mylist_a += i[0]
        elif i[1] == 1 and counter % 2 == 1:
            mylist_b += i[0]
mainlist = [mylist_a] + [mylist_b]
print 'list a: ' + str(mylist_a), 'list b: ' + str(mylist_b), 'counter % 2: '+str(counter % 2)
print mainlist
```

Output of mainlist:

```
>>>[['apples', 'strawberries', 'garlic'], ['grapes', 'pears', 'pineapples']]
```

This method is incorrect because I want the user to define the number of lists using a function and for the items in the "inlist" list to be distributed among all of the lists that are defined.

If the user wants 3 lists, the result would change to something like this:

```
>>>[['apples', 'pears'], ['grapes', 'garlic'], ['strawberries', 'pineapples']]
```

Comment: So you basically want to "modulo" lists over sublists?

Comment: I want to, yes, but I can't get the syntax right when the number of lists is dynamic.

Comment: are you sure that the number of available elements is *always* dividable by the number of sublists you want?

Comment: So you actually want to filter `[item for item, flag in inlist if flag == 1]` and then de-interweave?

Comment: No, I forgot to mention that the 'inlist' variable is entered by the user, so that list may grow or shrink dramatically.

Comment: Is the output expected to be deterministic? That is, if I specify _n_ lists, the same items appear in only one of the _n_ lists, and always the same list each time?

Comment: Each item from 'inlist' should only appear in one of n lists, but should not reoccur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like:

```
def distribute_sublists(inlist,n=2):
    sub = [x for x,avail in inlist if avail]
    return [sub[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

where `inlist` is the list of tuples, and `n` is the number of "groups" over which you want to divide them. In a first step we construct a subresult `sub` of all elements **that are available**. In the second step we using *list comprehension* and the *slice operator* `i::n` to construct a sublist starting from `i` and make *hops* of `n`.

This gives:

```
>>> distribute_sublists(inlist,n=1)
[['apples', 'grapes', 'strawberries', 'pears', 'garlic', 'pineapples']]
>>> distribute_sublists(inlist,n=2)
[['apples', 'strawberries', 'garlic'], ['grapes', 'pears', 'pineapples']]
>>> distribute_sublists(inlist,n=3)
[['apples', 'pears'], ['grapes', 'garlic'], ['strawberries', 'pineapples']]
>>> distribute_sublists(inlist,n=4)
[['apples', 'garlic'], ['grapes', 'pineapples'], ['strawberries'], ['pears']]
>>> distribute_sublists(inlist,n=5)
[['apples', 'pineapples'], ['grapes'], ['strawberries'], ['pears'], ['garlic']]
```

So it will distribute the first item to the first list, the second to the second until all *n* lists have one element, the next element will than be assigned to the first list again and so on in a *Round Robin* fashion.

The algorithm runs in *O(n)* with *n* the number of elements in `inlist` (not to be confused with the `n` in the function).

Comment: Dan D's solution was roughly what I did while putting together the answer. But I like the cleverness of this solution best because it avoids the step of producing a separate enumeration by using slicing with a step.

Comment: I had to break down what you did here, but I was excited to see that your result efficiently solved the problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

This filters the list and then deinterweaves it.

```
inlist = [('apples', 1), ('oranges', 0), ('bananas', 0), ('grapes', 1),
          ('strawberries', 1), ('pears', 1), ('cucumbers', 0), ('lettuce', 0),
          ('tomatos', 0), ('onions', 0), ('garlic', 1), ('pineapples', 1)]

from itertools import cycle, izip

def deinterweave(L, n):
    r = [list() for _ in range(n)]
    for item, o in izip(L, cycle(r)):
        o.append(item)
    return r

filtered = [item for item, flag in inlist if flag == 1]

print deinterweave(filtered, 2)
print deinterweave(filtered, 3)
```

Shows that:

```
>>> print deinterweave(filtered, 2)
[['apples', 'strawberries', 'garlic'], ['grapes', 'pears', 'pineapples']]
>>> print deinterweave(filtered, 3)
[['apples', 'pears'], ['grapes', 'garlic'], ['strawberries', 'pineapples']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create `main_list` without `sublists` and then divide them into numbers of `sublists` based on user input, something like this :

```
import more_itertools
inlist = [('apples', 1), ('oranges', 0), ('bananas', 0), ('grapes', 1),
          ('strawberries', 1), ('pears', 1), ('cucumbers', 0), ('lettuce', 0),
          ('tomatos', 0), ('onions', 0), ('garlic', 1), ('pineapples', 1)]
main_list = [txt[0] for txt in inlist if txt[1]]

list_count = 3

sub_lists = [list(elem) for elem in list(more_itertools.distribute(list_count, main_list))] 
print sub_lists
```

This will result in :

```
[['apples', 'pears'], ['grapes', 'garlic'], ['strawberries', 'pineapples']]
```

You will need to import module `more-itertools` for this solution to work.